# How to display a different image everyday

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'd like to create an android application (with android studio) that display a different image every day.

For example I want to show, on my application home, an image called "IMAGE1" only in Monday, "IMAGE2" only in Thursday and etc...

Is it possibile? I'd like to know too if it's possible to change the main activity every day, for example "PAGE1" for monday and etc...

Thank you guys!!

Comment: What class is your image objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want it's just change the images on specific days. 
It's not complicated and you do not need to change pages for that. In your main activity you can do it here is what I propose :

```
import java.util.Calendar

ImageView imageView;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(now_date);

imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY){

   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMAGE1);
 }else if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.TUESDAY){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMAGE2);
}
....
```

the same for the other days of the week, 
I hope it helped you

Comment: Calendar class is terrible, and was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

## `DayOfWeek` & `Map`

Use the `DayOfWeek` enum as the key to a `Map` where the value is your image object.

```
Map< DayOfWeek , java.awt.Image > dowToImage = Map.of( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , mon , …
```

If Android does not support `Map.of`, use `EnumMap`.

Get today’s date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
```

Interrogate for day of week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

Do a lookup into our map.

```
Image image = dowToImage.get( dow ) ;
```